# Can I create a SQLALCHEMY model from the pure sql CREATE?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlalchemy

I am checking SQLAlchemy and it's models and I was wondering if having the raw CREATE sql from a database, I can create the models automatically or do I have to create them by hand class per class?

So instead of writing every table in a class with every field and it's attributes, just extract the SQL CREATE statement and pass it to any function that outputs a model, or even use the SQL directly with no need to create a model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can create model objects from an existing schema written with SQL. See the [reflection](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/reflection.html) feature.